# Getting latitudes and longitudes of an address string using SAS

Tags: sas

I have an address string in SAS. I want to find out the exact longitude and latitude for that address. Is there any way in SAS that i can do it? I tried using proc geocode but it does not give me accurate results-

```
proc geocode                           /* Invoke geocoding procedure       */
method=STREET                       /* Specify geocoding method         */
data=WORK.CUSTOMERS                 /* Input data set of addresses      */
out=WORK.GEOCODED                   /* Output data set with X/Y values  */
lookupstreet=SASHELP.GEOEXM         /* Primary street lookup data set   */
attributevar=(TRACTCE00);           /* Assign Census Tract to locations */
run;
```

Most of the times it can't provide me with an exact latitude and longitude and returns the zip code of the address.

Answer (score 2):

Did you obtain the correct street lookup data sets? The example datasets (GEO*) in SASHELP only includes streets in Wake County, North Carolina.

Additional data can be downloaded from [SAS Maps Online](http://support.sas.com/rnd/datavisualization/mapsonline/html/geocode.html) at the SAS support site.

The output dataset from the PROC GEOCODE includes if and how an address is matched. What do the columns `_MATCHED_, _STATUS_, _NOTES_ and _SCORE_` say when no latitude/longitude coordinates are returned?